# Xcode 4.2 documentation, clarification needed

Tags: xcode4.2

I have Xcode 4.2 installed and had documentation updated

[image]

However clicking on keyword like `strong` provides no doc references

[image]

I feel like i am missing something still.

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is fine, there's nothing missing. Quick Help is not provided for compiler directives and built-in keywords and data types.

You'll notice that quick help is unavailable for keywords like @interface, @property, nonatomic, readonly and so on. Likewise, built-in data types like int, float, double don't have quick help either. This is normal.

If you need help on the ARC keywords like strong, weak, __unsafe_unretained I suggest to read the [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html).

For compiler directives please refer to my [Complete List of Objective-C 2.0 @ Compiler Directives](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/10/complete-list-objectivec-20-compiler-directives/).